# Returning a value from a Swift function containing a closure

Tags: ios, swift, function, completionhandler

I've written a function that should return a value but the value comes from a closure. The problem is if I try to return a value from inside the closure it treats this as being the return value from the completion handler.

```
private func loadData() throws -> [Item] {
    var items = [Item]()
    let jsonUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?units=metric&cnt=7&q=coventry,uk"
    print(jsonUrl)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    guard let shotsUrl = NSURL(string: jsonUrl) else {
        throw JSONError.InvalidURL(jsonUrl)
    }
    session.dataTaskWithURL(shotsUrl, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])
            print(json)
            guard let days:[AnyObject] = (json["list"] as! [AnyObject]) else {
                throw JSONError.InvalidArray
            }
            for day in days {
                guard let timestamp:Double = day["dt"] as? Double else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidKey("dt")
                }
                print(timestamp)
                let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(timestamp))
                guard let weather:[AnyObject] = day["weather"] as? [AnyObject] else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidArray
                }
                guard let desc:String = weather[0]["description"] as? String else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidKey("description")
                }
                guard let icon:String = weather[0]["icon"] as? String else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidKey("icon")
                }
                guard let url = NSURL(string: "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(icon).png") else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidURL("http://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(icon).png")
                }
                guard let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidData
                }
                guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidImage
                }
                guard let temp:AnyObject = day["temp"] else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidKey("temp")
                }
                guard let max:Float = temp["max"] as? Float else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidKey("max")
                }
                let newDay = Item(date: date, description: desc, maxTemp: max, icon: image)
                print(newDay)
                items.append(newDay)
            }
            return items // this line fails because I'm in the closure. I want this to be the value returned by the loadData() function.
        } catch {
            print("Fetch failed: \((error as NSError).localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You can pass a closure as a callback or a completion handler, which you can call at the place you want to return the items. You need to write how you're willing to handle the data in the closure which you pass to the loadData() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a completion handler (named `dataHandler` in my example) to your `loadData` function:

```
private func loadData(dataHandler: ([Item])->()) throws {
    var items = [Item]()
    let jsonUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?units=metric&cnt=7&q=coventry,uk"
    print(jsonUrl)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    guard let shotsUrl = NSURL(string: jsonUrl) else {
        throw JSONError.InvalidURL(jsonUrl)
    }
    session.dataTaskWithURL(shotsUrl, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])
            print(json)
            guard let days:[AnyObject] = (json["list"] as! [AnyObject]) else {
                throw JSONError.InvalidArray
            }
            for day in days {
                guard let timestamp:Double = day["dt"] as? Double else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidKey("dt")
                }
                print(timestamp)
                let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(timestamp))
                guard let weather:[AnyObject] = day["weather"] as? [AnyObject] else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidArray
                }
                guard let desc:String = weather[0]["description"] as? String else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidKey("description")
                }
                guard let icon:String = weather[0]["icon"] as? String else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidKey("icon")
                }
                guard let url = NSURL(string: "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(icon).png") else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidURL("http://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(icon).png")
                }
                guard let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidData
                }
                guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidImage
                }
                guard let temp:AnyObject = day["temp"] else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidKey("temp")
                }
                guard let max:Float = temp["max"] as? Float else {
                    throw JSONError.InvalidKey("max")
                }
                let newDay = Item(date: date, description: desc, maxTemp: max, icon: image)
                print(newDay)
                items.append(newDay)
            }
            dataHandler(items)
        } catch {
            print("Fetch failed: \((error as NSError).localizedDescription)")
        }
    }).resume()
}

do {
    try loadData { itemsArray in
        print(itemsArray)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

I've tested it in a Playground and it works without errors:

[image]

Comment: The answer should work but it throws runtime errors in a playground (even when including the struct and error enum). I then tried making the method public in a class and calling it from my view controller. No errors but the session.dataTaskWithURL callback fails to run.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my Playground running my answer without errors. Please have a look. // Don't forget that in order to run asynchronous code in a Playground you need to enable `XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely`! :)

Comment: Apologies, forgot to add XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(true)